# Remove :hover with Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

In the chrome developer tools, you can toggle an element's state to be :hover.

Is there therefore a way, that javascript (or library) can remove the :hover of an element, without ending in another state? (E.g. leaving an extra class behind.)

Answer (score 0):

You can just add another class to the element that you want to apply the hover state and remove it when needed.

For example, add class `hoverClass` to your div:

```
<div class="fixedClass hoverClass"></div>
```

and then apply `:hover` on `hoverClass` instead of `fixedClass`:

```
.hoverClass:hover{background:red}
```

Then you can use removeClass() whenever you want:

```
$('div.fixedClass').removeClass('hoverClass');
```

Comment: But then you'd need to reintroduce the class (when?), ready for the next hover.

Comment: Then you can use `addClass()` ?

Comment: Not immediately you can't, as it's not effective. There seems to need to be a mouse event occur between to prevent the hover from coming straight back.